# Read in lines of code from a file and randomly execute one of the lines

Tags: python

I might have explained it weirdly in the title, but here is the issue I have. I am making a small sentence-generating program and to choose the sentence, it chooses a random sentence structure.

I want to have a file with the different structure codes on separate lines, like this:

```
random.choice(blankThat)+" "+sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(description)+"."
random.choice(questionBegin)+" "+sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(pastDescription)+"?"
random.choice(pastBegin)+" "+sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(pastDescription)+"."
random.choice(subjectBegin)+" "+sentenceSubject+"."
random.choice(subjectQuestion)+" "+sentenceSubject+"?"
sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(description)+"."
sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(pastDescription)+"."
random.choice(subjectBeginExclaim)+" "+sentenceSubject+"!"
random.choice(songList)+" "+random.choice(["is","was"])+" "+random.choice(adverbs)+" "+random.choice(adjectives)+"."
sentenceSubject+" "+"is"+" "+random.choice(describers)+"."
```

How would I then randomly choose to execute one of the above lines of code? I tried using this simple code to randomly choose one...

```
templateFile = open("structures.txt","a+")
templates = templateFile.readlines()
templates = [y.strip() for y in templates]
finalSentence = random.choice(templates)
```

But when I `print(finalSentence)`, it just spits out one of the lines instead of executing it:

```
random.choice(pastBegin)+" "+sentenceSubject+" "+random.choice(pastDescription)+"."
```

How can I just randomly choose and execute one of the lines? I'd prefer it if I can read in the structures from a file, as I will regularly be adding new sentence structures.

Comment: Why do you even need to store the python commands of how to generate the sentences in an extra text file? You can just add these few lines in your original python document and then pick the parts randomly there.

Comment: So eval() will do what you want, but the real question is how you can better store or generate this information. Where are you getting the information from that makes a text file necessary? How are you piecing these structures together? Do they need to be created manually?

Comment: @FlashTek That is exactly what I was doing and it only took up around ten lines of code, but I plan for it to make a **very** large variation of sentences which would quickly become annoying for me. I understand that it's not a huge issue, but it's what I'd be more comfortable with :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think it could prove helpful. Consider different ways of constructing and generating this information. Here is a simple and imperfect example, but I think it could be a good place to start:

```
import random

subject = "Jeremy"
descriptions = ["cool", "tall", "strong"]
hobbies = ["running", "coding"]

def sentence_maker3000():
    sentence_vals = {"subject": subject, "descriptions": random.choice(descriptions), "hobbies": random.choice(hobbies)}
    valid_sentences = ["{subject} is {descriptions}", "{subject} likes {hobbies}"]

    sentence = random.choice(valid_sentences).format(**sentence_vals)

    return sentence

print(sentence_maker3000())  # Might print "Jeremy is cool" or "Jeremy likes coding"
```

You can construct all your valid sentences using Python's formatting brackets. Very easy to read and much shorter to write.

You can write these valid sentences in a separate text file like so:

```
{subject} is {descriptions}
{subject} likes {hobbies}
```

and then replace the `valid_sentences` assignment with:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    valid_sentences = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: @DYZ it was a direct answer to the question, so that's understandable. Hopefully, he still reads the other answers and maybe gets some ideas. I remember when I first started I didn't really understand why I should avoid eval() when writing a private program, but I learned that its use was usually a symptom of less-than-ideal construction. I think he'll find the same thing to prove true.

Comment: @illiteratecoder Ok, final decision. I'm still quite new to Python programming but I really like your method, so I'll use that for now :)

Comment: @YasathDias I'm glad you've given eval() the ol' boot. Formatting is super useful, and just in case you aren't familiar, `.format(**sentence_vals)` takes all the keyword arguments from `sentence_vals` and writes them into the parenthesis. In this case, it's equal to `.format(subject=subject, descriptions=random.choice(descriptions), hobbies=random.choice(hobbies))`. That's why you can just write the keyword in brackets like `{subject}` in the string. Just in case you didn't know :)

Comment: Wow, I never knew about that! Thanks for the knowledge; it's working really well in the program and I can now easily expand it using semi-natural language! It's helpful to have it like that because if I choose to allow other people to contribute to it, they'll be able to easily understand how to make their own sentence structures :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sketch of what you can do. It looks like each line of your file uses three types of expressions:

- string literals like `" is "`,
- references to constant strings, like `sentenceSubject`, and
- random choices from string collections, like `random.choice(blankThat)`.

Create a mini-language that can recognize these expressions. E.g.:

```
?blankThat " " !sentenceSubject " " ?description "."
```

Create a dictionary of all constant strings, e.g.:

```
strings = {"sentenceSubject" : "Hello, world", ...}
```

Create a dictionary of all string collections, e.g.:

```
collections = {"blankThat" : ["foo", "bar", ...],
               "description" : ["dog", "cat", ...], ...}
```

Write a mini-parser that takes a string written in your mini-language, breaks it into expressions, determines the type of each expression by the first character of the token, and converts it to the proper string:

- ?X -> random lookup, find X in `collections`, call `random.choice(collections[X])`
- !X -> constant string, find `strings[X]`
- "X" -> string literal, just use X

Finally, combine all translated pieces. Hope it helps.

Comment: I provided an alternative to using eval() as well, but I like your answer, it's a good way to think.

Comment: @illiteratecoder Yup, yours is good, too. I think mine is a bit more general.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print(eval(finalSentence))
```

instead of `print(finalSentence)`. What `eval(str)` does is it takes a string and runs it like it would have been normal code.

Comment: Your answer was downvoted (not by me) because https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @dyz is there any other method to execute an string statement? I think there isn't any other alternative of the given situation.. is there?

Comment: @DYZ I'm sure that no-one will sabotage my text file, but if a real risk is posed, how else would I carry out the desired task?

Comment: @YasathDias don't design your program around evaluating strings?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not very helpful advice :\